# Pandas merge_asof only return one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes on closest date using `pd.merge_asof`. If there are multiple rows with that date, it still only returns a single row. I figured I could just use the date that it matched on and do an exact merge afterwards, but it seems like an unnecessary step if it could simply be done in one. As i understand it, `pd.merge_asof` should act as a left-join.

```
df = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        voyages,
        rates,
        left_by="PeggedRoute",
        right_by="Route",
        left_on="CommenceDate", 
        right_on="RateDate",
        direction="backward", 
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta("30 days"),  
    )
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you read the docs, you will observe that it only returns one row per entry

Comment: I see.. Would be a nice addition :) Thanks

Comment: Your code is not nearest though, it is less than right? Kindly share sample dataframe with expected output